# Arrays - Orderby - Types

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, types

Setting up a program overview which runs over four (4) days: Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday. All events *(movies, events, seminar, workshops ++)* are listed within the `post type` `event`.

I am going to divide the queries into each day, meaning in the `args` the `date` should be set.

The end result should be similar to this:

```
Wednesday

11:00

<---- Events which starts at 11:00 ---->

12:00

<---- Events which starts at 12:00 ---->
```

And the next page:

```
Thursday

11:00

<---- Events which starts at 11:00 ---->

12:00

<---- Events which starts at 12:00 ---->
```

*And so on.*

I have started on the PHP, but stopped where I realised I needed to combine the `args` with information made with `Types`.

Each event has `post type event` and defined a `date`. This is not the regular `WordPress post date` when the article is made. Meaning `orderby date` would be useless.

Excerpt:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'event',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

**Note:** Right now it sorts after `post date` as explained above, but this is not correct, and won't work.

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?> <!-- Listing all the events -->

<div id="isotope-list">

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 

<div class="col-md-4"> <!-- Each event should be in this div -->

<?php
$value = types_render_field('dato');
if ( !empty($value) ) { 
echo do_shortcode( '[types field="dato" format="g:i"][/types]' ); 
echo " |";
}
else { echo ""; }
?>

</div> <!-- End col-md-4  -->
<?php endwhile;  ?>
</div> <!-- End isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**I believe that should explain the problem, how I am thinking, where I need help and what I have tried. If you have any questions please ask.**

The page can be found here: http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/dokfilm/ *(Scroll to Program)*.

Sorry that the site is on Norwegian. Translated:

Onsdag - Wednesday, Torsdag - Thursday, Fredag - Friday, Lørdag - Saturday.

**Updated**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
           'key' => 'dato',
           'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
           'compare' => '>=',
           'type' => 'date'
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'meta_key' => 'dato',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    );
```

**Update 2**

With good help from David

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); 
?>

<?php $x= 0;

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?> <!-- Listing all the events -->

<div id="isotope-list">

    <!-- open the first day -->
    <div id="isotope-day">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

            $newtime = false;
            $date = types_render_field('dato', array("format"=>"U"));//get a unix date, i'm not sure of the dateformat you are using but it should be ok..if not ref strtotime for your date format
            $now = strtotime('now');

            if($date < $now){
                continue;
            }

            //do we need a new day?? yes if not the same date!
            if( date('d/m/Y', $date) !== $curdate  || !isset($curdate) ){
                $curday = date('l', $date );
                $curdate= date('d/m/Y', $date);
                $newdate= true; 
                $x++;
            }

            //do we need a new time??
            if( date('H', $date ) != $curtime || !isset($curtime) ){
                $curtime = date('H', $date );
                $newtime= true; 
            }

        ?>

        <?php if($newday): ?>

        <?php if ($x>0):?>
        </div> <!-- End previous day when adding a new one except in first instance -->
    </div> <?php endif; ?>

    <div id="isotope-day">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1><?php echo $curday.' '.$curdate; ?></h1>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($newtime) : ?>
            <h2><?php echo $curtime; ?>:00</h2>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="content grid lefttext maximg littluft">
                        <div class="red-overlay">
                            <figure>
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('event_thumb'); } ?>
                                <figcaption class="absolute-bottom">
                                    <div class="littpaddingleft">
                                        <h2 class="whitetext nomarginbottom jubilat"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                        <p><span class="whitetext thin">

                                        <?php
                                            $value = types_render_field('dato');
                                            if ( !empty($value) ) { 
                                            echo do_shortcode( '[types field="dato" format="G:i"][/types]' ); 
                                            echo " |";
                                            }
                                            else { echo ""; }
                                        ?>
                                        <?php
                                            $value = types_render_field('type');
                                            if ( !empty($value) ) { 
                                            echo $value;
                                            echo " |";
                                            }
                                            else { echo ""; }
                                        ?>
                                        <?php
                                            $value = types_render_field('stad');
                                            if ( !empty($value) ) { echo $value; }
                                            else { echo ""; }
                                        ?>

                                        </span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </figcaption>           
                            </figure>  
                        </div> 
                    </div>   
                </a> 
            </div> <!-- End col-md-4  -->                         


    <?php
        // increase our counter... 
        $x++;
        endwhile;  
    ?>

    </div> <!-- Close col-md-12 -->
    </div> <!-- close final day -->
</div> <!-- End isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Having troubles with `$curdate` and so on... The page can be found here: http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/dokfilm/ *(Scroll to Program)*.

`var_dump($posts)` echoed this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#130 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(26) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 14:07:20" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 13:07:20" ["post_content"]=> string(56) "Verdas trivlegaste dokumentarfilmfestival fyllar 20 år!" ["post_title"]=> string(39) "20 år med Dokfilm – 27. til 30. mars" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(32) "20-ar-med-dokfilm-27-til-30-mars" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 14:07:20" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 13:07:20" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(42) "http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/dokfilm/?p=26" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [1]=> object(WP_Post)#113 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(1) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 13:13:22" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 12:13:22" ["post_content"]=> string(101) "Velkommen til WordPress. Dette er ditt første innlegg. Rediger eller slett det, og start bloggingen!" ["post_title"]=> string(12) "Hei, verden!" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(10) "hei-verden" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 13:13:22" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-23 12:13:22" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(41) "http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/dokfilm/?p=1" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "1" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }
```

Meta key: `wpcf-dato`. Meta value: `1458741600`

Comment: i guessing if you have a custom date, its in the post meta column which is not datetime, can you change from using a date to unix time stamp? Otherwise you will need to loop with php which is ok if you only have 1 page but not if you have a few pages.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can get the timeformat just as the in Wordpress Codex. Meaning if I change format to `format="U"` it should echo the unix time stamp. If this is want you meant.

Comment: no, outputting is not the issue, you can try a meta query but it will probably not work with a string but worth a try, other than than you can do this with php, but the trade off is performance and paging.

Comment: Thank you again. I belive I can't be far away from the solution. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the date meta query only works (supposedly) with YYYY-mm-dd stored dates, I had issues before with correctly stored dates so best option is to actually store a unix date (contains numbers), so the greater the number the greater the date.

But because you are returning all the posts and not using the paged functions you can just not display the events that have expired

something like this should work:

```
<?php 
// your query args...
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
           'key' => 'dato',
           'value' => strtotime('now'),
           'compare' => '>=',
           'type'    => 'numeric',
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-dato',
    'order' => 'ASC', // sort ascending, we want the nearest dates to display first?
    );


$the_query = new WP_Query($args);





$x= 0;

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?> <!-- Listing all the events -->

<div id="isotope-list">

    <!-- open the first day -->
    <div id="isotope-day">

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $newtime = false;
        $date= strtotime( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dato', true) ); //get a unix date, i'm not sure of the dateformat you are using but it should be ok..if not ref strtotime for your date format
        $now = strtotime('now');

        if($date < $now){
            continue;
        }


        //do we need a new day?? yes if not the same date!
        if( !isset($curdate) || date('d/m/Y', $date) !== $curdate   ){
            $curday = date('l', $date );
            $curdate= date('d/m/Y', $date);
            $newdate= true; 
            $x++;
        }

        //do we need a new time??
        if( !isset($curtime) || date('h', $date ) != $curtime  ){
            $curtime = date('h', $date );
            $newtime= true; 
        }

    ?>

    <?php if($newday): ?>

        <?php if ($x>0):?>
            </div> <!-- End previous day when adding a new one except in first instance -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="isotope-day">
        <h1><?php echo $curday.' '.$curdate; ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($newtime) : ?>
            <h3><?php echo $curtime; ?>:00</h3>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- your event here -->
    </div> <!-- End col-md-4  -->

    <?php
        // increase our counter... 
        $x++;
        endwhile;  
    ?>

    </div> <!-- close final day -->

</div> <!-- End isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that brief. I changed a little bit for the `$date` so it returned unix time stamp. Please see updated question. Still having some troubles, do you have any ideas why?

Comment: what are the issues? so you are saving a unix time in the db or just converting afterwards?

Comment: Not sure how Types works, but right now it's converting to Unix Timeformat. The issues are that `curtime` and `newday` are undefined variables. Also it does not sort after unix time, but when the posts are published... Any ideas?

Comment: yes you need to get a sorting function, if the dates are saved as a unix timestamp, you can use mysql to re-arrange if not it will have to be php loop (not the most efficient way to do this). Just define the variables below `$newtime=false` I forgot to add these in. If you var_dump($posts) and post the structure above, I can show you how to sort them with php or if the dates are saved as unix, i can show you the mysql way (meta query)

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what format the dates are saved as, sorry. Which variables do you want me to define? :) I included `var_dump($posts)` below `WP_Query($args);`. But not sure if that was correct (?). Please see updated question.

Comment: can you var dump get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dato', true) as well?

Comment: Included `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dato', true));` after `while` and the following shows up next to each and every posts: `string(0) ""`

Comment: have a look in your post meta table to see what the field where your date  is stored is actually called

Comment: Thank you. Here you go: Meta key: `wpcf-dato`. Meta value: `1458741600`

Comment: Thank you. However the page turns out blank. No errors or anything, just blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: you will need to echo a few variables and test all the code above to find where the issue is!